# PyQt4.QtGui Fatal Python error: Illegal instruction

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, pyqt4, raspbian

I'm trying to run a Python PyQt4 program on Raspbian OS, but it fails to execute. On Windows it works fine. I found out that the error happens when QtGui is imported.

What is strange to me is that some modules load normaly (PyQt4.QtCore), but others raise an error and restart the shell (PyQt4.QtGui, PYQt4.QtTest, PyQt4.QtHelp).

Here is the error from Python shell:

```
>>> import PyQt4
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
Backend terminated (returncode: -4)
Fatal Python error: Illegal instruction

Current thread 0x76fc2010 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 914 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1016 in _handle_fromlist
  File "<pyshell>", line 1 in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/backend.py", line 588 in execute_source
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/backend.py", line 427 in _execute_source_ex
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/backend.py", line 404 in _execute_source
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/backend.py", line 167 in _cmd_execute_source
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/backend.py", line 119 in handle_command
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/backend.py", line 97 in mainloop
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/backend_launcher.py", line 41 in <module>
Resetting ...
>>>
```

First I tried updating the device...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

... but it didn't solve the problem.

So i tried reinstalling python3 and pyqt4, which also didn't help.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-pyqt4
```

If I check the pyqt4 module all the packages should be installed.

```
sudo apt-cache show python3-pyqt4

Description: Python3 bindings for Qt4
 PyQt4 exposes the Qt4 API to Python3. The following modules are supported:
  * QtCore
  * QtDBus
  * QtGui
  * QtNetwork
  * QtXml
  * QtScript
  * QtSvg
  * QtTest
  * QtAssistant
  * QtOpenGL (in python3-pyqt4.qtopengl)
  * QtSql (in python3-pyqt4.qtsql)
  * phonon (in python3-pyqt4.phonon)
Description-md5: 54b67afe2dab0fdf3d94483cba3da06a
```

Additional info:

- Raspberry Pi 3, ARMv7
- OS: Linux raspberrypi 4.9.80-v7+ #1098 SMP Fri Mar 9 19:11:42 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
- Python version: python3 (3.5.3)
- PyQt version: pyqt4_4.11.4

Comment: Is the raspberry in question Raspberry Pi 1 (armv6)?

Comment: @J.J.Hakala No, its Raspberry Pi 3 and armv7.